# Why is this matrix-transformation true? (determinant)

Tags: matrices, determinant

Why is $\det
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1-x_0 & (x_1-x_0)x_1 & \cdots & (x_1-x_0)x_1^{n-1} \\
\vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
x_n-x_0 & (x_n-x_0)x_n & \cdots & (x_n-x_0)x_n^{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}
$

equal to

$$(x_1-x_0) \cdot (x_2-x_0)\cdots(x_n-x_0) \cdot \det\begin{pmatrix}
1 & x_1 & \cdots & x_1^{n-1} \\
\vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
1 & x_n & ... & x_n^{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}$$

I don't see how we can factor this out.

Answer (score 3):

You extract the factor $x_1-x_0$ from the first line of the matrix, you extract the factor $x_2-x_0$ from the second line and so on. Don't forget that $\det$ is a multilinear map.

Comment: I would like to see the rule for that

Comment: The rule is: if $A$ and $B$ are square matrices of the same size, if $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ and if each line of $A$ is equal to the corresponding line of $B$, except that the $i^\text{th}$ line of $A$ is the $i^\text{th}$ line of $B$ times $\lambda$, then $\det(A)=\lambda\det(B)$.